# Дебаг приложения create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я создал реакт приложение через `react-create-app`. И в одном из компонентов допустил ошибку. Вместо обработчика `onClick` передал строку `{...}`. Мне в браузер выплюнулась ошибка, что мол в качестве обработчика ожидается функция, а передано строка, но в каком файле, в какой строке это - непонятно.

Ошибку тычет мне на строку рендера основного компонента в dom-элемент, а в качестве файла показывает `bundle.js`, собранный веб-паком. Как сделать, чтобы указывал на мой файл `component.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дебаг включается путем запуска приложения npm start.
Но для начала нужно в файле package.json вписать следующий скрипт:

```
 "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000"
```

Answer (score 2):

@Эдуард вот [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) расширение для хрома специально для дебага реакта от самого создателя реакта

только настроить не забудьте что бы работало. там пару галочек поставить надо.
[вот тут смотри](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools)